# BS4 Script not consistently scraping traget value, not generating error

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

A while back I created a BS4 script to scrape off individual stock ticker market values from Yahoo Finance. The purpose being to update a personal finance program (individual use not commercial).

The program worked flawlessly for months, but recently it stopped working 100%. It appears to have a 25-50% success rate. The errors that do generate from the script are associated with the fact that a value was not obtained. I can not figure out how to generate an error as to why a value wasn't found/scraped for one execution but not another execution of the same script.

like each time I run the script it will work sometimes but not other times. I have adjusted the script to just execute on a single user input ticker instead of pulling a list from a database. Any thoughts as to where I am going wrong?

An attempt at debugging was the addition of `print(soup)`. the idea was to ensure something was being obtained. Which it appears to be doing. However, the `soup.find_All()` aspect seems to be the point of random success.

[as an aside I may find an api to switch to in the future but for educational and proof of concept I want to get this to work.]

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl
import os
import time
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

def scrape_value(ticker):
    ticker_price = ""
    # For ignoring SSL certificate errors
    ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
    ctx.check_hostname = False
    ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

    print(f"ticker: {ticker} - before scrape")
    url = f'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{ticker.upper()}?p={ticker.upper()}&.tsrc=fin-srch'
    req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Chrome/79.0.3945.130'})
    webpage = urlopen(req).read()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, 'html.parser')
    print(soup)

    for span in soup.find_All('span',
                             attrs={'class': "Trsdu(0.3s) Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(b)"
                                    }):
        ticker_price = span.text.strip()
        print(ticker_price)

    return ticker_price


if __name__ == '__main__':
    scrape_value('F')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use different approach, how to select the element. Observing the HTML source, the quote is in `<span>` with `data-reactid="32"`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def scrape_value(ticker):
    url = f'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{ticker.upper()}?p={ticker.upper()}&.tsrc=fin-srch'
    webpage = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Chrome/79.0.3945.130'}).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, 'html.parser')
    ticker_price = soup.find('span', {'data-reactid': "32"}).text
    return ticker_price


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for ticker in ['F', 'AAPL', 'MSFT']:
        print('{} - {}'.format(ticker, scrape_value(ticker)))
```

Prints:

```
F - 6.90
AAPL - 369.44
MSFT - 201.57
```

Comment: It appears that the **'data-reactid** changes every time it loads the site. At least that appears to be the issue I am having. I ended up switching to the free API TIINGO. Not exactly what i wanted to do. However, it works and faster than beautiful soup. 

I at least know it isn't my code per say. I guess it's an anti scraping method, or at least hindrance.